# How to make an update view for partial updates in rest

Tags: django, rest, view, patch

Im new at rest and im trying to make a partial update of a model.
I get an ajax request that has these fields:

```
{"object":modelToBeUpdated,
 "id":ObjectIdToBeUpdated,
 "field":fieldOfTheObjectToBeUpdated,
 "value":theValue}
```

I have no idea how to use it in the patch or update view... any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the app name you can use `get_model` from `from django.db.models.loading import get_model`.

```
from django.db.models.loading import get_model

json = {"object":modelToBeUpdated,
        "id":ObjectIdToBeUpdated,
        "field":fieldOfTheObjectToBeUpdated,
        "value":theValue}

model = get_model("appname", json["object"])

model.objects.filter(pk=json["id"]).update(**{json["field"]: json["value"]})
```

I have not tested this though.

You could probably also do something like this:

```
object = model.objects.get(pk=json["id"])
setattr(object, json["field"], json["value"])
object.save()
```